# Multi-label classification done right?

Tags: r, machine-learning, weka

Let's say I have a dataset, which can be neatly classified using weka's J48 or randomForest in R.
Now let's say I have an other training file, which contains two classifications per datapoint.

How could I combine these two to be able to classify new data points into these two classes?

(So I'd need a "two-pass" training.)

Should I use a MLP (like a restricted Bolzmann machine) instead?

Comment: you could ask on http://www.crossvalidated.com

Comment: And when you do that, you should be more detailed, I'm not quite sure what your setting is.

Comment: what do you mean by "what my setting is"? I have a file with a bunch of data with exactly one class, and an other file with two classes provided per data point. I'd like to use the first one to enhance the training, and to match exactly two classes for a new data point.

Comment: +1 to asking on Crossvalidated

Comment: Are the two data sets over the same set of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your two data sets look like this...

**Data set 1:**

```
(x_11, x_12, ... , x_1N) = 1
(x_21, x_22, ... , x_2N) = 0
....
```

**Data set 2:**

```
(x_11, x_12, ... , x_1N) = (1, 1)
(x_21, x_22, ... , x_2N) = (0, 1)
....
```

Assuming that is what your problem looks like, I would split it into two problems: that of predicting the two different labels. I think this can be justified by the probability formula:

```
p(L1,L2|X) = p(L2|L1,X)p(L1|X)
```

where the L1 and L2 are the two class labels and X is the data.

My suggestion is to train a model for p(L1|X) using datasets 1 and 2 and L1 as your target variable and then train a model of p(L2|L1,X) using dataset 2 and L1, with L2 as your target variable. To predict a new pair of labels, you apply the first model to get an estimate of L1 and then the second model using the estimate of L1 to get an estimate of L2.

I suppose an argument against this approach is that, although the formula is true, it may be the case that p(L1,L2|X) is easier to learn than p(L2|L1,X) and p(L1|X). However, in the absence of more details I really don't know.